# Angular Laravel JWT get authenticated user

Tags: php, angular, laravel

I'm developing an Angular + Laravel app. I did a register-login with JWT and it works fine, I get the token and I store it in localStorage, the log out works too. But I have a problem with identifying the logged user. The me function is always returning a null json, why ? I searched for a solution online but nothing helped

**AuthController**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
}

public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or password doesn\'t exits.'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}

public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());
    return $this->login($request);
}

public function me()
{   
    return response()->json(Auth::guard()->user());
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard()->logout();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}

public function refresh()
{
    return $this->respondWithToken(Auth::guard()->refresh());
}

protected function respondWithToken($token)
{
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => Auth::guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
        'user' => Auth::guard()->user()->name
    ]);
}
```

**config/auth**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

Comment: What if you use `response()->json(Auth::guard()->user());` ?

Comment: Didn't work, i get 401 Unauthenticated

Comment: Try replace every `auth()` with `Auth::guard()` in this controller.

Comment: Still getting 401

Comment: Where is `function respondWithToken`?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the respondWithToken too

Comment: Ok, you can go back using `auth()` as in original code. Does the angular code using the token to do the requests? Can you show us how do you create the request and pass the `accessToken`?

Comment: That was the problem i forgot about the accessToken in frontend. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are excluding `me` method from the `auth:api` middleware in your controllers constructor;

Change this:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register','me']]);
    }
```

to this:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login','register']]);
    }
```

Comment: I did this and now i get 401 Unauthenticated

Comment: Are you passing the token from Angular? `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 0):

You're not use default guard ,
so you should select api guard
with auth('api')
or auth()->guard('api')
and me function need authorization